# defining a many-to-one reference in a Slick case class

Tags: slick

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705194) answers how to define a one-to-many association, by defining a method in the "one" case class (`Directorate`) that returns a `Seq` of the "many" class (`ServiceArea`).
But it doesn't address the "bidirectional" part of the question.

Using that example, I'd like to see how to traverse the association from the other direction.
Instead of

```
case class ServiceArea(areaCode: String, dirCode: String, name: String)
```

I'd like to see

```
case class ServiceArea(areaCode: String, directorate: Directorate, name: String)
```

Is this possible with Slick?
Because when I try something like

```
object ServiceAreas ...
  def * = areaCode ~ directorate ~ name <> (ServiceArea, ServiceArea.unapply _)
```

it fails to compile, not finding an implicit value for evidence parameter of type `TypeMapper[ForeignKeyQuery[ServiceAreas,ServiceArea]]`.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147362) my answer? "Slick is not an ORM"?

Answer (score 7):

You have to adjust your way of thinking a little. Slick handles composition and execution of queries, but as you mentioned in your comment, it's not an ORM (thank goodness).

Have a look at the code you referenced:

```
case class ServiceArea(areaCode: String, dirCode: String, name: String)

object ServiceAreas extends Table[ServiceArea]("SERVICE_AREAS") {

  def areaCode = column[String]("AREAE_CODE", O.PrimaryKey)

  def dirCode = column[String]("DIRECTORATE_CODE")

  def name = column[String]("NAME")

  def directorate = foreignKey("DIR_FK", dirCode, Directorates)(_.dirCode)

  def * = areaCode ~ dirCode ~ name <> (ServiceArea, ServiceArea.unapply _)
}
```

The link to `directorate` is already defined by a navigatable foreign key.

So now you can write a query like this:

```
   def directorates = for {
    area <- Parameters[String]
    sa <- ServiceAreas if sa.areaCode === area
    dir <- sa.directorate
  } yield dir
```

Which will yield a Directorate for each match.